# C++ error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Array<int>&’ from expression of type ‘int’

Tags: c++

I'm using a template class Array to implement a template class Matrix of T that acts like a 2D array. I have a function that is supposed to get a row of the matrix.

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(): rows(0), cols(0), data(){}

    Matrix(int rows, int cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols), data(rows, Array<T>(cols)) {}

    Array<T>& operator[](int row) {
        return data[row];
    }
    // other functions

private:
    int rows, cols;
    Array<Array<T>> data;
};
```

Array:

```
template<typename T>
class Array {
public:
    Array(): len{0}, buf{nullptr} {
    }

    explicit Array(int len) : len{len}, buf{new T[len]} {
    }
    // copy constructor, move constructor, destructor
    int& operator[](int index) {
        if (!in_bounds(index))
            throw std::string("Exception operator[](" + std::to_string(index) + ") Out Of Range");
        return buf[index];
    }
    const int& operator[](int index) const {
        if (!in_bounds(index))
            throw std::string("Exception operator[](" + std::to_string(index) + ") Out Of Range");
        return buf[index];
    }
private:
    int len; 
    T* buf;
    bool in_bounds(int index) const {
        return index >= 0 && index < len;
    }

};
```

The line `return data[row];` appears to give the error mentioned.
I looked at other solutions to this error and still didn't understand it. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What is `Array<T>`?

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Array<T> is a one-dimensional array from the Array template class. each row in the matrix is an Array<T> object.

Comment: @Neeraja So I think you need to show us the definition of `Array` and also where it is in the code in relation to your definition of `Matrix`. You've shown us an error message that specifically mentions `Array` yet you haven't shown the definition of `Array`.

Comment: `data[i]` is, presumably, an `Array<T>`; `data[i] = cols;` in the constructor doesn’t look right. But it’s impossible to say without seeing the definition of `Array`. Where did the error message point?

Comment: Thanks for the quick update! `Array<T>::operator[](int index)` should probably return a `T&` instead of an `int&`.

Comment: the error message pointed to return data[row]; in operator[].

Comment: @churill I think that was my mistake! thanks a lot. but as mentioned by Pete Becker, my constructor is wrong as well and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Neeraja I think I've straightened that out in an answer below. Thanks for making the question answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Matrix` constructor taking `rows` and `cols`

```cpp
Matrix(int rows, int cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols), data(rows, Array<T>(cols)) {}
```

tries to initialize the `data` member using a constructor that takes an `int` and an `array<T>`.

`data` is defined as

```cpp
Array<Array<T>> data;
```

and `Array` does not have a constructor taking an `int` and an `Array`. You could make the constructor only taking `len` also take an optional `T` and use that to assign values to the `Array`:

```cpp
explicit Array(int len, T copy = {}) : len{len}, buf{new T[len]} {
    std::fill_n(buf, len, copy);
}
```

You also need to change your `Array::operator[]`s to return a reference to `T`, not `int`. Your `Array`s stores `T`s (whatever they may be), not `int`s. In your case, you have one array where `T = int` and another where `T = Array<int>`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5hTrPoh58)

Suggestion: Use `std::size_t` for the sizes instead of `int`.